# Gutenberg blocks - only allow as innerblock

Tags: block-editor

I'm looking to develop re-usable innerblocks that can only be used as innerblocks, including removing them from the list of blocks someone can choose from in the editor.

I know in the inner block's block.json declaration I can set the parent like this:

```
"parent": [ "my-namespace/my-outer-block" ]
```

And within the parent block I can do the following:

```
const ALLOWED_INNER_BLOCKS = [ 'my-namespace/my-inner-block' ];
```

This is unfortunately, the only way I know of for removing the block from the list of blocks that a user can choose from in an editor. Any way around this? I feel like I need to register a duplicate block and set a different parent in order to accomplish this at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: parent is an array, have you tried passing multiple values?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yup it's an array but I'd love to not have to append to it every time I'd like to use a child block on another parent. Much easier to set allowed inner blocks in order to avoid technical debt.

Comment: You might need to provide more context here. It’s not clear to me why that’s a problem. If you want to restrict a block to being used in particular blocks then listing them is only logical.